# Trying to install linux

Tags: system-installation

I have 3 partitions (C,D,E). I don't want to give up data in D and E, I want to write over C which has Windows 10 in it, and want to install linux there. How can I do this?

Comment: Umm … so you want to completely eliminate Windows? Based on the way the question was written, this may not be the best way forward. Perhaps you could start with a VM and “fall back” to Windows when needed 

Comment: Try and learn more about your device before you install; C, D & E are labels used by windows, and are not actual partitions (they do represent partitions, but partitions do not have letter names; ie. no C, D or E as they are given by windows during windows boot).

Comment: I recommend reading books about Linux before installing it. If you know someone familiar with a Linux distribution, get help from him and bring him your laptop. Be sure to **backup your important data** on *external* media before.

Comment: Backup your important data, my friend. Copy them into another storage disk you have before proceeding to the installation.

Comment: Linux does not have Windows tools to repair NTFS partitions. If you need chkdsk, defrag or other repairs to NTFS you need Windows. Best to backup data and restore to ext4 format if you want to convert. Or to start probably better to dual boot. Do you have room on drive for another partition for Ubuntu? If so shrink Windows using Windows tools to make space & reboot as NTFS requires chkdsk after any resize. Also make sure Windows fast start up or hibernation is off, otherwise NTFS will be read only in Linux.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend Kubuntu for someone coming from windows. First boot into the live USB and make sure that your hardware works properly in Linux. Next in the installer delete the windows partition (Be sure that it is the windows partition not a data partition) and use the newly free space for installation.

Comment: I support this recommendation as Kubuntu has very similar user interface and experience to Windows. Once you are accustomed to, you can learn another things later relatively quicker and easier.

Comment: Yes. First of all, I would suggest checking the amount of free space on the C drive. If there is enough free space, you can easily shorten this partition using MS Windows tools and install Linux on the free space.